# Anonymous class not found after Obfuscating in Android

Tags: android, obfuscation, anonymous-class

I need some number of items from Javascript, so I am using the Gson to convert the JSON string into values as like the below code.

**From Java script:**

```
 var  Items = [{ "ItemName": "Item1", "ItemPos": "1", "ItemValue":"value1"},{ "ItemName": "Item2", "ItemPos": "2", "ItemValue":"value2"}];
```

**Invoking Native Android method** passing these values as **JSON.parse(items)**.

In Native class I have retrieved these values as below,

```
 List<Items> ItemsList; 
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 ItemsList= gson.fromJson(args[0].toString(), new TypeToken<List<Items>>(){}.getType());
```

I have declared the Item class as below.

```
  public class Items
   {
    public String Name;
    public String Position;
    public String Value;

  }
```

These method of implementation works fine in the native source. But after obfuscating the source these method of implementation is not working. I am getting "**Lookup failed**" error. While decompile the obfuscated code, the Item class is not present in that place **"anonymous class not found"** is present. Even the declaration of the **List ItemsList is also not present**. How to resolve this issue?

**EDIT 1 :
MyProguard.pro**

```
-injars       input.jar
-outjars      output.jar
-libraryjars  android.jar
-libraryjars  android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars  annotations.jar
-libraryjars  gson-2.2.1.jar


-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
            SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep public class * {
  public protected *;
 }

-keepclassmembernames class * {
  java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
  java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
   native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
 }

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
 }

 -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
 -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
 -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

 -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
     public <init>(android.content.Context);
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
     public void set*(...);
  }

 -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
  }

 -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
  }

 -keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
    public void *(android.view.View);
    public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
   }

  -keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
      static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
   }

 -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
     public static <fields>;
  }
```

I have obfuscated the source by "**java -jar proguard.jar @MyProguard.pro**"

Comment: Maybe you could tell us HOW you obfuscate your code (proguard, ...) and what configuration you use. I think that's the most relevant part.

Comment: Hi,I have included the MyProguard.pro in my questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think that compiler may ignore the item class during Obfuscating

you must manually mention your missed class name in your proguard.txt file like as follows

-keep public class <your_class_name>
```

Refer this link [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#configuring)

it may be help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried in this way, It's keep the class Items. But in the retrieving of the javascript json values, I am getting the Lookup failed message. List<Items> ItemsList; This is not present in the decompiled java file. How to keep these type of declarations in Obfuscation.

Comment: Are you using any third party jar file in your application?

Comment: Yes, I am using the gson-2.1.1.jar in my source. Using this Gson method only I am retrieving the JSON values.

Comment: then include your gson package name into your proguard-project.txt file and verify any sub classes,attributes you are forget to include. for eg, -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.* -ignorewarnings

Comment: Can you please give some more information about including gson package name into proguard-project.txt file.?

Comment: In ur project folder there is a file called proguard-project.txt 
# If your project uses WebView with JS,uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.*
-ignorewarnings Note:  If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface 
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#} in your proguard-project.txt

Comment: I have already uncomment the above lines. The List<Class> object and the public class Items{} is not present in the obfuscated jar file. I have given -keep public class com.example.Android.NativeMethodProcessClass$Items in the MyProguard.pro file. But, still the class is not present in the Obfuscated jar file. Is anyother things have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
-keep class com.xxx.yyy$Items { *; }
```

Comment: I have included the above attributes, Still getting the Lookup failed error. While decompiling the obfuscated jar file, getting "Anonymous class not  found" error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using this Items class as a inner class of NativeMethodProcessClass, Now I am giving com.example.Android.NativeMethodProcessClass$Items{*;} in the Proguard.pro file. But getting "member class not found" in the decmpiled file. Is anything have to change in the Proguard?

Comment: Hi OcuS, Is any other things have to do in my proguard.pro file.? Please give some suggestions.